# Taylor series for linearization

Tags: taylor-expansion, linearization

I need to apply Taylor series to linearize following equation

$$f_{dr}= Au'+ Bu + C u^2 +D$$

Here, $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ are constants and $$u'=\frac{{\rm d}u}{{\rm d}t}, u=\frac{{\rm d}x}{{\rm d}t}$$

While applying Taylor series should I differentiate with respect to $t$ or $u$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Did you mean $f_{dr}$ ? And do you mean u is a derivative, making u' a 2nd derivative?

Comment: Yes actually u is velocity and u' is acceleration if we write in terms of displacement u=x' and u'=x''